# ObjectInputStream hanging

Tags: java, sockets

The client-side of my "Socket to ServerSocket"-implementation looks like this, but it never gets past the `ObjectInputStream`-initialization. I have tried commenting out the line, and the following print-statement is then executed. The connection is (at least initially) successful, and the ServerSocket reports of a successful connection.

**Client**

```
try(
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
) { 
    System.out.println("Connection and IO established");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Server**

```
while (true) {
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Client has connected!");         // This always prints
    new Thread(new ServerThread(clientSocket)).start();
    System.out.println("ServerThread has started");      // This as well
}
```

Comment: Did you wrap your server - side sockets stream in object streams aswell?

Answer (score 0):

The ObjectInputStream blocks waiting for the construction of the peer's ObjectOutputStream. Clearly the peer isn't constructing one, or possibly needs to flush it immediately after construction if you have a BufferedOutputStream in the stack.

Or possibly it is itself hung up constructing an `ObjectInputStream` because your *client* isn't constructing an `ObjectOutputStream.` The solution to that is to always construct and flush the `ObjectOutputStream` *before* the `ObjectInputStream.`

Comment: The documentation says that it waits also for the serialization of a Java instance's header. Furthermore we cannot know if the ObjectOutputStream is open by the server, because we don't have the ServerThread's source code.

Comment: @robermann The documentation *also* says that the header is written by the constructor of ObjectOutputStream. We can certainly know that the header hasn't arrived. Ergo either it hasn't been flushed or an ObjectOutputStream isn't being constructed at all. QED